# Find $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt3, \sqrt{5},2^{\frac13}):Q]$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

$[Q(\sqrt3, \sqrt5:Q]=4$

$$
\begin{matrix}
&  & \mathbb Q(\sqrt3, \sqrt{5})(2^{\frac13}) &  & \\
& \stackrel{a}{\diagup} & & \stackrel{b}{\diagdown} \\
\mathbb Q(\sqrt3, \sqrt5) & & & & \mathbb Q(2^{\frac13}) \\
& \stackrel{c}{\diagdown} & & \stackrel{d}{\diagup} \\
& & \mathbb Q
\end{matrix}
$$

We know $d=3$ and $c=4$ so $a \le 3$.

Finding $a$: I think I can prove that $2^{\frac13} \notin Q(\sqrt3, \sqrt5)$ and then $x^3-2$ is the minimal polynomial since its roots are not in $Q(\sqrt3, \sqrt5)$ so $a=3$ and the answer is $12$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Yes indeed $2^{1/3}\notin \Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}]$ because otherwise we would have

$$2=(a\sqrt{3}+b\sqrt{5}+c\sqrt{15}+d)^3$$

Reducing and regrouping this would lead to $\sqrt{\frac 53}$ rational. Contradiction.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $d\sqrt6 $ in the bracket too...

Comment: Also I guess I am correct with 12 right?

Comment: Yes you are. It is $12$. And there should be an $\sqrt{15}$ in the bracket